# 301 redirect - old domain to new not working with non www

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my old website f1arab.com to formulawahad.com with all the links inside. I used Wordpress which is installed in the wp_ar folder.

I put with a help of a friend this code in the htaccess that is available in the root (not wp_ar) but it seems to work only without "www" and it doesn't redirect inside links like f1arab.com/news/111 to formulawahad.com/news/111.

How can I achieve that?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^f1arab\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.formulawahad\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.formulawahad.com/$1 [R=301,L]

php_value memory_limit 1024M

<Files "config.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as the htaccess for the `f1arab.com` site should work. It will redirect all pages going to the old website to the new website (so `f1arab.com/about` will be directed to `www.formulawahad.com/about`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.formulawahad.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So do you suggest I remove the first 2 lines of the redirect? and keep the final line? so remove these? RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^f1arab\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.formulawahad\.com$   Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Since everything on the f1arab.com site is being redirected to formulawahad.com site, you should only need the two lines I have in my post.

Comment: Thanks, will it work for both (non www and wwww)? what I mean if I type f1arab.com will it send you to www.formulawahad.com? and if I type www.f1arab.com will it send you to www.formulawahad.com?

Comment: It will yes, everything will be redirected to the www version on the new site

Comment: Before I used it...I used this code...and my website went offline can't see any images/css at all..RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^f1arab.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.f1arab.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.formulawahad.com/$1 [L,R=301] 


After that, I tried your code and I still can't see...is there a way to fix the website? I don't know what happened..!!!

Comment: That's happening on the new website?

Comment: No on f1arab.com but now its working. Your code is directing f1arab.com to formulawahad.com (only homepage) if I go to http://www.f1arab.com/news/37255/ it doesn't redirect me to formulawahad.com/news/37255/ but it stays f1arab.com ...!

Comment: If the code in the answer above is what is in the htaccess file of the root folder of the f1arab.com website, it should (you probably should take out everything else from that file and only leave in the code i have above).

Comment: Wohooo it worked. Only I have a small problem with the new website. Please go to formulawahad.com - the logo URL is: http://www.f1arab.com/wp_ar/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/r07speedeffect-01.png  but if u click on it it redirects you to another link...same for the photos in widgets. How to fix that?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. It was a cache problem. You are the best :D